# How to set select2 option using only option value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 v4.0.1 select box which gets its options successfully updated by the function below.

```
function updateList(){

$("#myselect").html("");

    var updateList = {

        operation:"updateList"

    }

    $.post("myphp.php", updateList).done(function(response) {

    var counter = 0;
    var arrayLength = response.length;

    while(counter<arrayLength){

    var record = response[counter];
    $("#myselect").append('<option value="'+ record.id + '">' + record.name + '</option>')
    $("#myselect").select2();
    ++counter;             
};   
});
};
```

After this update, however, when I try to set selected option, the code below seems to work only for option values, but not for option text, therefore I get a selection which has no text in it.

```
function editTableUpdate() {

    var editTableUpdate = {

        ID: $("#selectrecord").val(),
        operation: "editTableUpdate"
    }

    $.post("myphp.php", editTableUpdate).done(function(response) {
       if(response.val != 0){ 

           var record = response[0];
           $("#myselect").val(record.id).trigger("change")
    }
  });

};
```

**Edit:** $("#myselect").html(""); removed from second function, I mistakenly put it in there while cropping necessary code. I keep having the problem.

**Edit 2:** While hovering over different options, this is where highligting happens in chrome's developer tools. Numbers at the end of highlights are id's in database, which I assign as option values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$("#myselect").html("");` inside your editTableUpdate function, which is clearing all options.

```
function editTableUpdate() {

    var editTableUpdate = {

        ID: $("#selectrecord").val(),
        operation: "editTableUpdate"
    }

    $.post("myphp.php", editTableUpdate).done(function(response) {
       if(response.length!= 0) {     
           var record = response[0];
           $("#myselect").val(record.id).trigger("change");
       }
  });

};
```

Comment: Sorry, that should not have been in there, the original code was like $("#editcname, #editcsurname, #editcgsm, #editcemail, #editcexp").val("");var updateEditPlc = {  cID: $("#selectclientedit")... etc, I cropped and edited it to reduce the amount of code you must go through. It is not there in original code, I corrected the snippet now. The problem remains, I do not originally clear options, they are inside #myselect, not deleted.

Comment: check the post method in my answer also, response.val != 0 is replaced with response.length !=0 inside if statement.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that would be better way to check. But response.val != 0 still working, function does not skip it; I've placed an alert to test before.

Comment: Another issue could be in $("#myselect").val(record.id), record.id is not present in option list.

Comment: record.id is present in option list, since I get exact same values from database. I also tried direct id that meets the record in database instead of record.id like .val("1") or .val(1), I still get an empty selection. response array makes a successful return from database and it works for all the other instances like text boxes, just not for select2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to [shi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6171211/shi)'s suggestions. I had 2 syntax errors in different bridge sections causing malfunctions but they were ignored by developers tool. Code works fine the way I posted it.